# When I focus on my password input, show/hide is not working on the first click. It is working fine in the second click

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I am using react-hook-form as a form library and yup schema for validation.

The issue is I added show/hide password functionality with an eye icon and simple Boolean state, but when I render on a page for the first time and click on input **(or focus on input)** and after clicking on the show password icon, nothing happens and validation occurs if I click again it is working fine. I am adding my HTML and validation code here.

HTML:

```
 <div className="form-field-wrapper input-password">
   <Input
     field
     type={isPasswordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'}
      name="password"
      label={<Translate>auth.signup.signup-form-section.password</Translate>}
      />
       <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsPasswordVisible(!isPasswordVisible)} className="show-password-icon">
          <Icon src={`${RESOURCE_URL}${isPasswordVisible ? '/eye.svg' : '/eye_close.svg'}`} height={24} width={24} />
        </button>
</div>
```

VALIDATION:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    password: yup.string()
      .required(<Translate field="Password">errors.required</Translate>),
  });
```

Form binding:

```
const formMethods = useForm({ mode: 'onBlur', resolver: yupResolver(schema), defaultValues });
```

How can I work on show/hide on the first click instead of triggering validation?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing seems to be because the form is being validated onBlur (when the focus leaves the input field) due to the configuration mode: 'onBlur' in useForm. When you click on the eye icon to show or hide the password, the input field loses focus, triggering validation before the state is updated to change the input type.

One way to potentially avoid this is to stop the propagation of the onClick event in your show/hide password button so that the onBlur event of the input field is not triggered when the button is clicked. You can do this by modifying your onClick handler like this:

```
<button 
  type="button" 
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setIsPasswordVisible(!isPasswordVisible);
  }} 
  className="show-password-icon"
>
  <Icon src={`${RESOURCE_URL}${isPasswordVisible ? '/eye.svg' : '/eye_close.svg'}`} height={24} width={24} />
</button>
```

This way, when you click the button, it should not trigger the onBlur event for the input field and therefore not trigger the validation.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, For answering but it is not working. I already tried this way :).

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?